# How to Display byte image on the asp.net page dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, image

I have loaded an byte array image from a web service to my asp.net website. 
I need to display it on the web page as soon as execute the web service.

I have tried using generic handler, but i could not do it since there wasn't way to pass byte[] image into the generic handler

```
void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    this.verifyTemplates();
    byte[] userImg;
    try
    {

        matchTemp.templateService hs = new matchTemp.templateService();
        bool s1 = hs.matchTemplates(template, out userID, out userName, out userImg);
// userImg is the byte image i need to display

    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
     //   vLabel.Text = exc.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the image data coming from? Where is the "generic handler" code? What exactly are you trying to do in the click event handler?

Comment: Please read - [Writing the perfect question](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Comment: Forget about the generic handler part

button2 is an asp button, at the click event i have executed a web service called matchTemplates and it gives few out parameters and last out parameter is a byte [] image.

i need to display that image on the page

Comment: There are no controls that allow that. You need to use an `image` control and point its source to a `HttpHandler` that returns the dynamic image. There are many questions and answers on SO describing how to achieve that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [Data URL](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/).  You can get the base64 of a byte array like this (change the image type as required)

```
string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(userImg);
string imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
```

In the view:

```
<img src='"<%=imageSrc%>"' />
```

This won't work in IE 7 or earlier, if you need to support those then you'll want to look at [MHTML](http://www.phpied.com/data-uris-mhtml-ie7-win7-vista-blues/).

Comment: Seeing as converting to Base64 adds about 30% to the size of the encoded value, this may not be an option.